# Streaming all nodes from DSE Graph using Gremlin

Tags: gremlin, tinkerpop3, gremlin-server, datastax-enterprise-graph

I am using *DataStax Enterprise Graph* and would like to stream all nodes from the graph database to my app using Gremlin.

*Note*: I'm communicating with *Gremlin server* via a WebSocket using sessions for persistent variables.

To do so without pulling all nodes in memory, I first create an iterator on the server:

```
// called once
iter = g.V();
```

I then progressively read the iterator into a buffer and return the content of the buffer:

```
// called multiple times, until it returns an empty array
results = []
while (itemStream.hasNext() && results.size < 5000) {
    results.push(itemStream.next())
}
return results
```

I used to do this with *TitanDB* and it worked okay (couple thousand nodes read per second).

With *DSE Graph* it is much slower (330 reads per second) and I get the following error error after having read just 400'000 nodes:

> Operation timed out - received only 0 responses.

Is there a better way to do this in *DSE Graph*?